# How to use token with request in vuejs

Tags: node.js, vuejs2

I have developed a backend for my small school system that allows different roles to access different endpoints, for example, a teacher cannot access the "/admin" endpoint for instance. What I have so far is an endpoint for register and, login, admin, and profile page and I have tested these with backend they all work fine.

I managed to create a registration form that would post data to the backend and a login form that request a login from the server and stores the jwt to the local storage.

Now, from the backend its easy to just test it with the postman and use the jwt for a request to a specific route.

How I am supposed to tackle this in Vue.js

And Can I approach this problem the same way as I am using Postman?
And how do I use the jwt in each request

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion state of the art solution is to paste your JWT token into HTTP Heaters for each and every request created from the client

As far as I get it from this [page](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/231) you do something like this

> `Vue.http.put('foo/bar', {foo: 'bar'}, {
>      headers: {
>          Authorization: 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=='
>      }
>   });`
>
> The HTTP methods take a third argument that allows you to specify headers to send >along with the request, I hope this helps.

This should also solve the problem of adding it to every request.

I suggest you use Vue Docs. to learn more about it. 
You should also understand the downsides of this method in terms of security. I think it is a good idea to check for client activity and destroy token in some period of inactivity.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much Fleix Riverwood.